# React - event.target returns the innerText of the previously clicked element instead of the currently clicked element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a drop down menu that returns a selected option through an event handler when the option is clicked.

When I click on the option, I target the `innerText` of that option via `event`. It looks like this: `event.target.innerText`. The selected targets value is then used to fill in an 'input' to show the users selected value. Exactly how you expect a `<select>` input to work. The targets value is also used for filtering listed components, but that is not what I am worried about here.

When the drop down menu component loads, inside of a `componentDidMount()` method, the state is updated with a default value so that the drop down menus load with the first option pre-populated (this is so that they are not empty before a user selects an option).

When I click on an option to make a selection, the returned `event.target.innerText` is of the previous selection. So if `option 1` was the default value when the component mounts, and then I select `option 2` and `console.log` the result, the value would be `option 1`. If I then select another option, `option 3`, the returned `console.log()` would be `option 2`. It's one behind.

In this .gif, you can see that when `componentDidMount()` fires, it `console.log()`s the default values of the drop down menu. But when I make a selection, you'll notice the `console.log()` is only returning the `event.target.innerText` of the previously selected option.

[image]

Here is the component:

```
class DropDownSelect extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    const { inputOptions } = props;
    const { option1 } = inputOptions;
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showOptions: false,
      selectionMade: option1
    };
  }

  setShowOptions = () => {
    const { showOptions } = this.state;
    this.setState(prevState => ({ showOptions: !prevState.showOptions }));
  };

  setSelectionMade = event => {
    const { target } = event;
    event.stopPropagation();

    this.setShowOptions();
    this.setState({ selectionMade: target.innerText });
    console.log(this.state.selectionMade);
  };

  setDefaultSelectionOnLoad = () => {
    const { inputOptions } = this.props;
    this.setState({ selectionMade: inputOptions.option1 });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setDefaultSelectionOnLoad();
    console.log(this.state.selectionMade);
  }

  render() {
    const { showOptions, selectionMade } = this.state;
    const { inputOptions } = this.props;

    const inputOptionsArray = Object.keys(inputOptions);

    return (
      <DropDownSelectMenu>
        <DropDownSelectPlaceholder onClick={this.setShowOptions}>
          <p>{selectionMade}</p>
          <i>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCaretDown} />
          </i>
        </DropDownSelectPlaceholder>

        {showOptions ? (
          <DropDownSelectOptions>
            {inputOptionsArray.map((key, index) => {
              return (
                <DropDownOption
                  onClick={event => {
                    this.setSelectionMade(event);
                  }}
                  key={index}
                >
                  {inputOptions[key]}
                </DropDownOption>
              );
            })}
          </DropDownSelectOptions>
        ) : null}
      </DropDownSelectMenu>
    );
  }
}
```

The `DropDownOption` styled component is where the function that updates the selection in the state is added as an `onClick` handler. Since this component is a child, and you need to click the parent component to open the `DropDownOption` component, I thought that maybe the event handler was bubbling up and grabbing the `event.target` value from the parent, so I added `event.stopPropagation()` to the event handler function `setSelectionMade()`. This didn't do anything for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine, only this debugging method fails ;)

This is of the most common errors in react - expecting state update immediatelly just after `setState` call.

Read [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), please. Value can be read in setState callback.

You can simply `console.log(selectionMade)` in `render` (before `return (`) to get current value.

Comment: Thank you. I totally forgot this!